# Split the number and text in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column in my excel in the following format:

```
Column A
100 Test A
200 Test B
300 Test C
```

I want to open the excel and split the numbers and text separately into two columns such as:

```
Column A    Column B
100         Test A
200         Test B
300         Test C
```

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: You can use (e.g.) `Split(cellValue, " ", 1)`  What have you tried?

Comment: @TimWilliams is split a 2016 function?

Comment: No it's in VBA, since Office 2000 I think (Q is tagged with VBA)

Comment: DOH,  I missed the VBA part and just saw excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you overcomplicate things:

```
Option Explicit
Sub SplitCells()
Dim totRange As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim splitted() As String

Set totRange = Range("A1:A3")
For Each r In totRange
  splitted = Split(r.Value, " ")
  r.Value = splitted(0)
  r.Offset(0, 1).Value = splitted(1) & " " & splitted(2)
 Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, this provided me the same solution and also made the process easy. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Non VBA option

For column B

```
=--left(A1,find(" ",A1)-1)
```

and for column C

```
=right(A1,len(A1)-find(" ",A1))
```

Copy those down as required.  If for some reason you want the number kept as text and not converted to a number, drop the -- from the first equation.  Some other ways of converting your number as text to number are +0 or *1 at the end of the equation.  Basically put the number as text through a math operation and excel converts it to a number.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the help. I have a solution which works almost fine.

```
Private Sub SplitData()  
    Dim sourceSheetName As String
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim uboundMax As Integer
    Dim result

    On Error GoTo SplitterErr
    sourceSheetName = "TestSheet"
    If sourceSheetName = "" Then _
        Exit Sub

    Set sourceSheet = Worksheets(sourceSheetName)

    With sourceSheet
        lastRow = .Range(sourceColumnName & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        result = SplittedValues(data:=.Range(.Cells(1, sourceColumnName), _
                                             .Cells(lastRow, sourceColumnName)), _
                                partsMaxLenght:=uboundMax)

        If Not IsEmpty(result) Then
            .Range(.Cells(1, sourceColumnName), _
                   .Cells(lastRow, uboundMax)).value = result
        End If
    End With

SplitterErr:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then _
        MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
End Sub

Private Function SplittedValues( _
    data As Range, _
    ByRef partsMaxLenght As Integer) As Variant

    Dim r As Integer
    Dim parts As Variant
    Dim values As Variant
    Dim value As Variant
    Dim splitted As Variant

    If Not IsArray(data) Then
        ' data consists of one cell only
        ReDim values(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        values(1, 1) = data.value
    Else
        values = data.value
    End If

    ReDim splitted(LBound(values) To UBound(values))

    For r = LBound(values) To UBound(values)

        value = values(r, 1)
        If IsEmpty(value) Then
            GoTo continue
        End If

        ' Split always returns zero based array so parts is zero based array
        parts = VBA.Split(value, delimiter)
        splitted(r) = parts

        If UBound(parts) + 1 > partsMaxLenght Then
            partsMaxLenght = UBound(parts) + 1
        End If

continue:
    Next r

    If partsMaxLenght = 0 Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim matrix As Variant
    Dim c As Integer
    ReDim matrix(LBound(splitted) To UBound(splitted), _
                 LBound(splitted) To partsMaxLenght)

    For r = LBound(splitted) To UBound(splitted)
        parts = splitted(r)
        For c = 0 To UBound(parts)
            matrix(r, c + 1) = parts(c)
        Next c
    Next r

    SplittedValues = matrix


End Function
```

But the output of this piece of code is as follows:

```
Column A    Column B  Column C
100         Test      A
200         Test      B
300         Test      C
```

So still am working on this. Please let me know if something works out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Tim Williams the Split function is probably the best. If you don't want to use VBA you can try the built-in function Text to Columns.
Depending on delimiters etc. this will produce 3 columns:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Good option, but then one would need to go back an combine Test with the letter.  You could always go by the non delimited method if all the numbers are the same length roughly though.